# How to handle large Vault Size in Corda?

Tags: bigdata, corda

The data in our vault is manageable. Eventually, we would accumulate a large volume. It is not possible to retain such large data for every day transactions. We would want to periodically archive or warehouse the data, so that query performance is maintained.

May I know if you have thought about handling large scale datasets and what would be your advise.

Answer (score 4):

From the `corda-dev` mailing list:

> Yep, we should do some design work around this. As you note it’s not a pressing issue right now but may become one in future.
>
> Our current implementation is actually designed to keep data around even when it’s no longer ‘current’ on the ledger. The ORM mapped vault tables prefer to mark a row as obsolete rather than actually delete the data from the underlying database. Also, the transaction store has no concept of garbage collection or pruning so it never deletes data either. This has clear benefits from the perspective of understanding the history of the ledger and how it got into its current state, but it poses operational issues as well.
>
> I think people will have different preferences here depending on their resources and jurisdiction. Let’s tackle the two data stores separately:
>
> Making the relationally mapped tables delete data is easy, it’s just a policy change. Instead of marking a row as gone, we actually issue a SQL DELETE call.
>   The transaction store is trickier. Corda benefits from its blockless design here; in theory we can garbage collect old transactions. The devil is in the details however because for nodes that use SGX the tx store will be encrypted. Thus not only do we need to develop a parallel GC for the tx graph, but also, run it entirely inside the enclaves. A fun systems engineering problem.
>
> If the concern is just query performance, one obvious move is to shift the tx store into a scalable K/V store like Cassandra, hosted BigTable etc. There’s no deep reason the tx store must be in the same RDBMS as the rest of the data, it’s just convenient to have a single database to backup. Scalable K/V stores don’t really lose query performance as the dataset grows, so, this is also a nice solution.
>
> W.R.T. things like the GDPR, being able to delete data might help or it might be irrelevant. As with all things GDPR related nobody knows because the EU didn’t bother to define any answers - auditing a distributed ledger might count as a “legitimate need” for data, or it might not, depending on who the judge is on the day of the case.
>
> It is at any rate only an issue when personal data is stored on ledger, which is not most use cases today.